# Error: unknown type name 'LHASH' when building OpenSCEP

Tags: c, openssl, openscep

I'm trying to build this Service in Ubuntu: http://openscep.othello.ch/download/openscep-0.4.2.tar.gz .

I called: `./configure` and it worked as expected.

Next I called `make all -j4` there it says:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../include -I../libltdl -I../include -I/usr/local/ssl/include -DOPENSCEPDIR=\"/usr/local/lib/openscep\" -g -O2 -c init.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/init.lo
In file included from ../include/init.h:13:0,
                 from init.c:9:
../include/scep.h:84:2: error: unknown type name 'LHASH'
  LHASH  *conf;
  ^
```

I found the solution: just replaced LHASH with _LHASH and I got further.
Now I have the problem that this code relies on `#include <openssl/asn1_mac.h>` which is obsolete.

I miss many function with prefix: `M_ASN1_I2D_` can some one tell me if they have just moved, or are there new methods which have the same functionality?

Comment: If I am not mistaken... Use OpenSSL 1.0.2 rather than OpenSSL 1.1.0. You might also consider filing a bug report against OpenSCEP for lack of 1.1.0 support. If you do, then please point them towards [OpenSSL 1.1.0 Changes | Compatibility Layer](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes#Compatibility_Layer) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Just saw this question is open. can you post it as an answer it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Suggested by @jww i installed OpenSSL 1.0.2 rather than OpenSSL 1.1.0.